# How do I use numpy's pv function for calculating a present value without a pmt?

Tags: python, numpy, quantitative-finance

Here is the present value equation from finance I'm acclimated to:

http://financeformulas.net/Present_Value.html

However, numpy's pv expects something like `np.pv(rate=0.05/12, nper=10*12, pmt=-100, fv=15692.93)`.

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the net present value of $23,000 with a discount rate of 5% over 2 years (one period per year).

`np.pv(rate=0.05, nper=2, fv=23000)` is not permitted.

Is there something I'm not seeing? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula you linked to is simply the present lump sum that must be invested to grow to a certain amount over a certain time.  That is not what `numpy.pv` is.  As described in [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pv.html), `numpy.pv` is for answering the question (emphasis added):

> What is the present value (e.g., the initial investment) of an investment that needs to total $15692.93 **after 10 years of saving $100 every month**?

Crucially, this involves periodic additional investments.

The formula you linked to is much simpler than the formula used by `numpy.pv` (which can also be seen in the documentation), so you don't need any special function to compute it.  To answer your question, just write down the expression in your forumula directly:

```
 PV = 23000/(1.05)**2
```

If you really want to use `numpy.pv`, you *can* get your answer out of it just by setting `pmt` to zero:

```
 np.pv(rate=0.05, nper=2, fv=23000, pmt=0)
```

(The answer will be negative due to the convention that `pv` uses whereby negative amounts indicate money you must pay out.)

Comment: I thought perhaps that numpy's formula could be refashioned for my problem as well.

Comment: @KamuelaFranco: You can.  I edited my answer to show how.